# Remotely accessed database can be accessed on localhost but not from the server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, database-connection

I have deployed my web application (ASP.NET MVC 3 C#) locally on my own computer and then uploaded the files by FTP tools on Godaddy.com hosting server.
The website works like a charm except the database connection.
I have deployed the database by generating scripts of my tables and created a database in godaddy database server (SQL Server) and simply just executed the scripts to create tables with data inside it on the server database.
I have configured the web.config connection string according to the provider's guides on the connectionString.

The problem:

I have used the same web.config on both my local computer and also the files on the host server with the same connectionString and everything.

- When I run my not-deployed-version of my web application on my own local computer on localhost.. It can access the database perfectly without any issue in fetching the data.
- But when I open my Live website on internet, it gives me the "Resource not found" error.

I have mentioned the problem with customer service, they were checking everything in my hosting account for hours they did not find anything unusual or wrong with it. But the problem still exists.

So technically, I am using the SAME web.config trying to connect to the SAME database but it works locally, but not on the server.

Is there anything in ASP.NET MVC modeling that I have been missing or not aware of?
This issue is driving nuts. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CarContext" connectionString="Data Source=moamzia.db.10412552.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=myID; User ID=myId; Password='Mypassword';" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I also just realized that my links are not working on the internet. Could it be the way I uploaded my files were wrong or something? Because my controller and Model are both missing in the deployed version of the application.
Then how does the localhost ever find the controller when it's not in its files?

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your comments.

After a little more of research and investigation, I found out that the problem is something about IIS or compiler on the server or the file directories or something.
The reason I say this is that the website on the internet does not compile ANY C# codes at all. It just compiles the plain HTML and CSS files.

Also after few hours, now I get this error when I open the website on internet:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

However, unfortunately, I am not much familiar with IIS or its role in website deployment. Any information regarding this would be really helpful I suppose.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your connection string.

Comment: Can you publish your project using the "Publish" dialog for your project? (Right-click on project in Solution Explorer->Publish)

Comment: And of course I have replaced the MyId and MyPassword with my own.

Comment: I have already published my website using File System method in one-click Publish Web of Visual Studio 2012 web Express. After that I used Godaddy's FTP tools in their website to upload files.

Comment: So your code files (anything ending in .cs) aren't missing, they're just included in .dll files (in other words, they are compiled)

Comment: Oh okey! But then what would be the reason for the links to not work at all on the internet?

Comment: I just checked the source code of the page on internet.. this is the HTML code it generates after compiling: <a href="">. It's an empty reference, but in my own computer it has values.

Comment: @dakait I don't think this is the point. If I got it right, all resources are outside developer machine network.

Comment: @user1807954 Could this be Debug/Release configuration issue?

Comment: @DavidGoshadze, I do not think it has anything to do with Debug/Release as it does work in my local computer with the same configuration. However,I have few updates which might help you a lot in answering this question. I shall update now.

Comment: Do you have the same ASP.net server versions and configurations on your local and remote machine?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same ASP.NET 4.0 framework. Is there any other configuration that I need to be aware of tho?